# I messed with security tab of shared drive in windows 7

Tags: network-shares, ntfs, windows-registry

I deleted everything in the security tab for a shared drive and canceled it in the middle of propagation.

I'm not not able to even close the window without "an error occurred while applying security information to: \(shared folder)  access is denied"

So far I tried this:

1. [I get access denied](http://networking.nitecruzr.net/2005/09/server-access-authorisation.html)
2. [with this I get cdcd is not recognized as an internal or external command + I did install subinacl and did use (x86) as I'm on a 64bit os](http://www.windowsreference.com/security/reset-the-entire-registry-permissions-to-defaults/)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these examples in this Microsoft document:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162786

Based on your question, unless you are working on registry permissions, subinacl is the wrong command to use, and will make things more complicated.

Comment: cacls e:\ /t /e /g Administrators:f   and I get an access is denied

Comment: @Mike Try taking ownership first: TAKEOWN /f * /r /d y Do takeown /? at a command prompt to see the options.